# How to deploy the model using sagemaker which has no model artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I want to deploy the model which has no artifacts(model zip file) using sagemaker and use its endpoint in my application to get the results. Can someone help me in doing this

Answer (score 0):

The steps to deploy a model in SageMaker is to -

1. Create a SageMaker Model
2. Create an endpoint configuration
3. Create the endpoint

SageMaker needs to access to a `model.tar.gz` file stored in S3 with the model and code stored in it. You can also deploy a model by training an `Estimator` and deploying that to an endpoint.

You can not deploy a model that has no model artifacts to a SageMaker hosted endpoint.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-deployment.html

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own